# How to dispatch scroll UIEvent on an IFrame in a Firefox addon?

Tags: events, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to emulate the `scroll` event on an `iframe` in my Firefox addon. I used the code below, but it doesn't work and `iframe` scroll won't move. And another question for me is how `initUIEvent` knows which direction scroll event must be dispatched for? (Horizontally or Vertically)

```js
var windows = require("window-utils"),
    selectedBrowser = windows.activeBrowserWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser,
    contentWindow = selectedBrowser.contentWindow,
    document = selectedBrowser.contentDocument;

obj = document.getElementById("scrollable_frame");

evt = document.createEvent("UIEvents");

evt.initUIEvent("scroll", true, true,
windows.activeBrowserWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentWindow, 2);

obj.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code dispatches the event just fine. But it doesn't help solve your problem because it's the frame scrolling that triggers the `scroll` event, not the other way round. If what you need is to scroll the frame then you can choose the direct route: use [`window.scrollByLines`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollByLines) or [`window.scrollByPages`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollByPages):

```js
obj = document.getElementById("scrollable_frame");
obj.contentWindow.scrollByLines(1);
```

To scroll horizontally you can use [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollBy). This code will also trigger the `scroll` event as a side-effect.

Comment: and if i want to scroll an element, for example a scrollable `div`. how can i do that? there is no `scrollByLines` method for `div` elements.

Comment: @AramAlipoor: You can change [`div.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) and [`div.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft).